# Количество контрольных точек в HULL шейдере

Tags: directx, шейдеры, directx-11

На данный момент я изучаю шейдеры и сейчас остановился на hull/domain shaders. Я не смог найти нужную информацию, из-за чего у меня появилась небольшая путаница: почему hull шейдер может принимать и отдавать больше контрольных точек, чем в примитиве, с которым он работает?

Пример c [MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/direct3d11/direct3d-11-advanced-stages-hull-shader-design):

```
#define MAX_POINTS 32

[domain("quad")]
[partitioning("integer")]
[outputtopology("triangle_cw")]
[outputcontrolpoints(16)]
[patchconstantfunc("SubDToBezierConstantsHS")]
BEZIER_CONTROL_POINT SubDToBezierHS( 
    InputPatch<VS_CONTROL_POINT_OUTPUT, MAX_POINTS> ip, 
    uint i : SV_OutputControlPointID,
    uint PatchID : SV_PrimitiveID )
{
    VS_CONTROL_POINT_OUTPUT Output;

    // Insert code to compute Output here.

    return Output;
}
```

Почему здесь используется 32 контрольные точки в качестве входных данных и 16 в качестве выходных, а не 4 точки для обоих случаев?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В данном шейдере квадратный участок (quad) заданный 32 контрольными точками, поступающими из вершинного шейдера, аппроксимируется бикубическими кривыми Безье. Итого 16 выходных контрольных точек, примерно таких:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В domain шейдере на основании результата работы тесселятора и выхлопа hull шейдера вычисляются финальные данные вершин создавая более плавную поверхность, более близкую к полученным кривым.

Comment: Спасибо. У меня остался один вопрос, буду благодарен, если Вы на него ответите: Как располагаются входные контрольные точки, если мы используем triangle, а не quad?

Comment: @user263096 На самом деле как угодно. Хотя они называются контрольные "точки" или "вершины" и приходят из "вершинного" шейдера это просто произвольные входные параметры, которые даже не обязательно могут иметь какой-то строго геометрический смысл. Что они задают и как их интерпретировать почти полностью определяется шейдером.

Comment: Каким образом тогда можно найти итоговую позицию вершин в domain шейдере, если расположение контрольных точек на поверхности Безье неизвестна?

Comment: @user263096 Множеством способов. Например все 16 выходных точек можно расчитать по всего одной входной, если она задает параметры какого-то примитива. По аналогии с геометрическим шейдером.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, входные контрольные точки domain шейдера уже автоматически расположены. Их параметры можно модифицировать и использовать в качестве выходных данных. Мне конкретно интересен способ их расположения изначально: как, зная индекс контрольной точки, можно определить её барицентрические координаты?

Comment: @user263096 Стоп. Если говорить о domain шейдере, то он получает два набора входных параметров - те 16 выходных точек из hull шейдера (причем все сразу) и одну точку, рассчитанную тесcелятором и имеющую семантику `SV_DomainLocation`. Как вычисляются параметры выходной точки domain шейдере можно посмотреть в [примере из SDK](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Direct3D-Tessellation-70afba2c)